# Set style properties to a div in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with a listview, which has a div. This div has different background color according the database info:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvwPostArt" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsAdvanced" GroupItemCount="3" OnItemDataBound="lvwPostArt_ItemDataBound">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <p>No matches.</p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table style="border: none">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
            <!--HEEEEEEEERE'S THE DIV!!! -->
                <div id="divContainer" class="icondetail" runat="server" style='background-color:<%# Eval("colorFondo") %>'><!-- HERE GOES CUSTOM COLOR -->
                        <div class="innerBox">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_Post" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageThumbnail") %>' CssClass="StaticImage" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

However this is not receiving the color. the objectDataSource has the following DataObjectTypeName:

```
public class myImage
{
    string colorFondo { get; set; }
    string ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I tried so far:

Try #1: Set the databind directly on the div style.

```
<div id="divContainer" class="icondetail" runat="server" style='background-color:<%# Eval("colorFondo") %>'>
```

Try #2: Set the information on code behind by using the property ItemDataBound

```
protected void lvwPostArt_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl divCont = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divContainer");
            divCont.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffffff"); //How can I get the info from the DataClass to assign it to the property????
        }
    }
```

My question is, how can I assign a background-color to this div?

Comment: You can access `colorFondo` property by `(e.Item.DataItem as myImage).colorFondo`. `<%# Eval("colorFondo") %>` should work though; did you check the generated html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either like this

```
DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataItem.DataItem;
divCont.Style.Add("background-color", rowView["colorFondo"].ToString());
```

or like this

```
var myImg = e.Item.DataItem as myImage;
divCont.Style.Add("background-color", myImg.colorFondo);
```

Comment: Just great!! Thank you so much to you and mshsayem! Sorry I didn't reply before, I'm struggling with BSOD on my pc, so keeps rebooting a lot :S

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there... on your second try, just use this one

```
divCont.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#ffffff");
```

Comment: What is the difference then what he already did, divCont.Style do the same thing you are doing with attributes